# onedrivesdk not installing with pip

Tags: python, pip, onedrive

Trying to install onedrivesdk. Getting the following error.

```
pip install onedrivesdk
Collecting onedrivesdk
  Using cached onedrivesdk-2.0.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/ronnie/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/2l/ww686y_n7l5gg0k_5l8dvqm40000gn/T/pip-install-3bpo_kor/onedrivesdk/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/2l/ww686y_n7l5gg0k_5l8dvqm40000gn/T/pip-install-3bpo_kor/onedrivesdk/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/2l/ww686y_n7l5gg0k_5l8dvqm40000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-wu2injdc
         cwd: /private/var/folders/2l/ww686y_n7l5gg0k_5l8dvqm40000gn/T/pip-install-3bpo_kor/onedrivesdk/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/2l/ww686y_n7l5gg0k_5l8dvqm40000gn/T/pip-install-3bpo_kor/onedrivesdk/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        with open(NOTICE, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/private/var/folders/2l/ww686y_n7l5gg0k_5l8dvqm40000gn/T/pip-install-3bpo_kor/onedrivesdk/setup.py/../NOTICE.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: On linux onedrivesdk pip package has been broken for a while. You can install an older version if it works for you. I use "pip install onedrivesdk==1.1.8"

Comment: It seems that you does not use virtualenv?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/onedrivesdk/ This package has been deprecated and should no longer be used. To continue using the old version of this package, please install `onedrivesdk < 2`.

Comment: The onedrivesdk is no longer maintained. Replace with onedrivesdk_fork.
https://pypi.org/project/onedrivesdk-fork/
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/issues/182

Answer (score 0):

The package onedrivesdk has been deprecated.

https://pypi.org/project/onedrivesdk/

So it's no longer available for usage.